# revert re.sub backwards execution

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
data = re.sub(r'.*"md5": ', '', data, 1)
```

I am trying to use this in the first occurrence of a text file but it is starting from the last occurrence, executing backwards. So, when I do:

```
r = re.match('(.*?)}{"id": "', data).group()
```

It returns **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'** because *id* always appears before *md5*.

There is a way to revert this?

Comment: Looks like you are parsing JSON with regex. There is a json parsing module, you do not have to use a regex that is not safe for JSON parsing.

Comment: Thank you but probably I will need this in different files (not json). I am going to use json parsing right now but I would like to clarify this re.sub.

Comment: Could you explain what this question is about? It is rather unclear right now without a sample text and expected output. You cannot *revert* a `re.sub` operation. Nor change the direction the `re` engine matches in a string (though you may with `regex`).

Comment: If you need to match something that can be removed with the `re.sub`, run `re.search` before running `re.sub`.

Comment: Humm so there is no way to revert re.sub operation. Ok, I am going to try re.search. I was creating an example to show the expected output but I will try re.search before.

Comment: The point is that if you remove a part of a string that contained the expected match, you will not find that match - isn't that logical?

Comment: It is okay, before I have used "replace" with success but now I need something like "re.sub". The problem is in the order of "re.sub" operation.

Comment: Done! "data = data.replace(re.search(r'(.*?)"md5": "', data).group(), "", 1)" solved my problem.

Comment: You seem to need all text after the first occurrence of a `"md5": "` substring. Why not use [`re.search(r'"md5":\s*"(.*)', data, re.S)`](https://ideone.com/sVGPHA) and grab `m.group(1)` value?